# Bash script in a Lambda function

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Bash script that enables me to power down RDS clusters. However I would like to use it with a Lambda function. Is it possible in some way to use Bash in lambda? I cant see any option in the GUI so I dont think its possible but thought I'd ask in case someone has an option

Here is my script

```
for cluster in $(aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tag-filters Key=Instance,Values=${Env} --resource-type-filters rds | awk -F: '{print $NF}') ; do echo "Starting $clustername" ; aws rds start-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier $clustername; done
```

Comment: Rather than calling a Bash script, you should call the AWS CPI directly. You did not mention that language you are using in your Lambda function, but there would be an [AWS SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/tools) for it.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible. In the end a AWS Lambda is just a microVM running Amazon Linux. So running Bash scripts is possible.

But I would not recommend it. Before we go into what I would propose instead, I want to give you an overview of the two options you have if you absolutely have to run a Bash script.

### Option 1: Use custom runtime

AWS allows you to provide your own runtime (instead of using the default runtimes that AWS provides). This usually involves creating a Docker image or providing a custom runtime through the deployment package. You can find an example of this in the AWS documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-walkthrough.html

### Option 2: Run script from code

You could also just put the script in your deployment package and execute it in code:

Example in Python:

```py
import os

os.system('/path/to/script.sh')
```

### What you should do instead

But all of those options are not what you should do. I propose you write a Lambda function in one of the supported runtimes and use the AWS SDK to start your RDS clusters.

Comment: can you give an example in node js  ? thank you .